# Is this sequence going to infinity, and how do we know that?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

$a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {:} {b}} {b}} {b}} {b}=?$

I've tried letting $\quad a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {:} {b}} {b}} {b}=K$

Which makes the equation:

$a+\dfrac {K} {b}=K$ $\quad$  and  $\quad$ $a=\dfrac {bK-K} {b}$ $\quad$ and it'll be $\quad\dfrac {ab} {b-1}=K$

How we can say that is true?$\;$Where does that logic come from?

$a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {a+\dfrac {:} {b}} {b}} {b}} {b}=\dfrac {ab} {b-1}$

And other examples:

$\sqrt [n] {a\sqrt [n] {a\sqrt [n] {a\sqrt [n] {a\ldots }}}}=\sqrt [n-1] {a}\tag{1}$

$\sqrt [n] {a:\sqrt [n] {a:\sqrt [n] {a:\sqrt [n] {a:\ldots }}}}=\sqrt [n+1] {a}\tag{2}$

$\sqrt [] {a+\sqrt [] {a+\sqrt [] {a+\sqrt [] {a+\ldots }}}}=\dfrac {1+\sqrt {1+4a}} {2}\tag 3$

$\sqrt [] {a(a+1)+\sqrt [] {a(a+1)+\sqrt [] {a(a+1)+\sqrt [] {a(a+1)+\ldots }}}}=a+1 \tag4$

$$\boxed{\boxed{\text{HOW ??}}}$$

Comment: Before you can start wondering what the _value_ of the first expression is, you need to _define what it means_. A priori, things with dots in them do not necessarily mean anything until equipped with a definition. Once you decide on a definition (probably as a limit of a certain sequence), your reasoning shows at most that _if_ there is a value, _then_ that value with be $ab/(b-1)$; but it will require a separate proof to show that this is indeed the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this is handled in calculus courses is that you have to show that the sequence is, say monotone increasing and bounded from above. Then applying the least upper bound property of the real numbers you can conclude that the sequence converges.  Once you know it converges you can apply the argument you gave. However, checking boundedness and monotonicity can be the trickier part of the proof.